# Dovecot submission service: authentication failes

Tags: dovecot

I have trouble setting up submissions with Dovecot + Postfix.

`doveadm auth login user pass` gives the right output.

When I try to send a mail with submission(s) it gives authentication failed error.

`doveconf -n` output:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = " imap lmtp submission"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = < some_crt
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

Comment: How could we know if you don't share the configuration & the logs / errors you have got?

Comment: I edit the question. Please see the configuration. Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.3.0, Dovecot has provided the [Submission Server](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/submission_server/) feature, which is an authenticating proxy between MUA and MTA. Its main advantage is the BURL ([RFC 4468](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4468.html)) extension, which allows saving the message to the `Sent` folder at the same time it is delivered to SMTP.

On the other hand, it was implemented in 2017, just before the [RFC 8314](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314) made the STARTTLS *submission* obsolete. Personally I would recommend using the traditional way, where Postfix handles both SMTP for incoming mail and *submissions* (*implicit TLS* on port `465`) for outboud, authenticated mail. There, Dovecot provides the SASL authentication as explained in the two documentations:

- [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/) (Dovecot)
- [Postfix SASL Howto](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) (Postfix)

Your configuration with the current approach is **missing configuration for the [Relay MTA](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/submission_server/#relay-mta).** In other words, your Dovevot does not understand where the mail should be relayed.

> `submission_relay_host`
> Host name for the relay server (required).

If you want to keep this course, please edit your [`20-submission.conf`](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/main/doc/example-config/conf.d/20-submission.conf) with at least, e.g.,

```
submission_relay_host = localhost
```

Also, setting [`disable_plaintext_auth`](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/#core_setting-disable_plaintext_auth) to `no` is a huge security risk, and you should stick with the default `yes`:

> If `yes`, disables the `LOGIN` command and all other plaintext authentication unless SSL/TLS is used (LOGINDISABLED capability) or the connection is “secured”:
>
> - Client IP is in [`login_trusted_networks`](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/#core_setting-login_trusted_networks).
> - Client IP is from `localhost`, and it’s not coming from HAProxy listener.

Comment: Adding the `submission_relay_host = localhost` solved this issue.

Comment: RFC 8314 didn't make the Submission protocol obsolete; it made the accessing of Submission service _via the StartTLS port 587_ obsolete. The protocol remains, on port 465 (which is no longer SMTPS – it has been SubmissionS for quite a while now.)

Comment: @user1686: Thanks for the correction; updated in the answer.